# AEON Mining not using full CPU

Tags: cpu

So I have been getting into mining for a while now and I started mining AEON. I have the software downloaded and have the wallet/miner. I want to solo mine and so I use `./daeon` to get into the daemon. After that I use the command

```
start_mining Wmsog7mKUzvAXsGXkLo6VKcSgMQM9fxn8P1rV96sQJQzN5PWFGYbDLzLTGPusPTmR4dr3J5KywWpeFNtqfVRdVmZ2LWtULved threads=4
```

and no matter number I put in threads it gives the output

```
2017-Mar-28 22:09:25.277446 Mining has started with 1 threads, good luck!
```

and when I open another terminal and run `top` my CPU is only at 100%, I have four CPU Cores and would like to use 3, so that one can always have a break. To sum up How do I get more than one CPU Core mining and why is the treads issue happening/how can I fix it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start the miner from wallet. start_mining address n . n= number of threads